# What does the phrase "clipped out of the air" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrases

Here is a sentence from a golf app's description:

> Never be overconfident of your shot. Otherwise you will soon see it
>   get clipped out of the air by your opponent.

The app mentions that players swing their balls simultaneously. Does the phrase "clipped out of the air" simply mean "grounded" here? The preceding sentences mention the colliding of balls that have unexpected results.

Comment: I think the players swing their clubs, not their balls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "clipped out of the air" means that your opponent can do some kind of maneuver to *knock* your ball in mid-air.  What kind of maneuver this is, it's impossible to say without more context as, obviously, this is not a typical tactic in an actual golf game.

Please read the rest of the instructions carefully to see if there is any more information on how a player's opponent can interfere with a ball in flight.